# Azure Devops set max-age on index.html in Azure storage with Azure CDN on static web site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn, azure-static-website-hosting

So, I don't want my index.html on my static vue.js app to always be cached because of updates. I can set max-age in the storage explorer manually. I have a Azure CDN set up for this site, which I purge after every deploy, but I don't think this will always update current users because the max-age on the index.html isn't set.
Is there a way to set from CDN the max-age?
Or is there a azure cli command that I should use on devops deploy to set the max-age on the index.html file in storage.
I don't see much documentation on this, maybe the CDN just takes care of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the correct values for both the "server-side caching" by the CDN and the "local caching" by your browser. You need to set Max-Age on the blob to have it be always current in the CDN, while using the `Cache-Control` header on the Blob to have the browser always read the current version. This is also known as "Internal Max Age" vs "External Max Age"(Cache-Control) in CDN, though the naming varies depending on the provider.

See also my recent answer on this:
[How to stop index.html being cached by Azure CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557904/how-to-stop-index-html-being-cached-by-azure-cdn/61564812#61564812)

For me, I found it is usually sufficient to set the `Cache-Control` header in blob storage on the `index.html` in order to control both the server-side and the local caching. At least the Azure CDN Provider respects this for server-side as well, so you have minimal effort.

See also this code example if you want to add it to your pipeline:
https://schwabencode.com/blog/2019/05/03/Update-Azure-Storage-Blob-Properties-with-PowerShell

```
# Storage Settings
$storageAccount = "__storage account__";
$containerName = "__container name__";

# Blob Update Settings
$contentCacheControl = "public, max-age=2592000"; # 30 days
$extensions = @(".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".ico", ".png", ".css", ".js");

# Read all blobs
$blobs = az storage blob list --account-name $storageAccount --container-name $containerName --num-results * --output json | ConvertFrom-Json

# iterate all blobs
foreach($blob in $blobs)
{
    # use name as identifier
    $blobName = $blob.name;

    # get extension
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($blobName).ToLower();
 
    # update blob if extension is affected
    if($extensions.Contains($extension))
    {
        az storage blob update --account-name $storageAccount --container-name $containerName --name $blobName --content-cache-control $contentCacheControl
        Write-Host "Updated $blobName" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh you do with powershell instead of azure cli. Currently I just set manually in the blob, just for index.html and have that set to 1 min or so. Seems I can just use the lastline in azure cli in devops you have there with index.html, inside the index.html I can call version number of each new build of the js file built.